# How to remove parts of URL by rewrite in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I tried to apply other answers found on StackOverflow, but nothing worked.

I have old links in Google, which people are visiting, but the structure of my page has changed and if people call those links, the page will be displayed messed up.

I have links like these:

```
/PIXMA/Canon-PRINT-Inkjet/SELPHY-664425773
/PL/SQL-Timestamp/Dawsons-Integral-Calculator-903670995
/--/-HDPrime-Dictionary-E-K/두산동아-중학교-교과서2007개정-교육-과정-429617286
```

I want to keep only the last part behind the last slash, like these:

```
/SELPHY-664425773
/Dawsons-Integral-Calculator-903670995
/두산동아-중학교-교과서2007개정-교육-과정-429617286
```

My htaccess looks like this now:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots-subdomains.txt

#ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteRule ^cat/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ /404.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^cat/([a-zA-Z_-]+)$ /404.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^grossing/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ /404.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^app/([a-zA-Z_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ /$2-$3 [R=301,NC]

#This is the final output
RewriteRule ^(.+)-([0-9]+)$ appsite.php?title=$1&id=$2
```

As you see, there are some rewrite rules already there, which I want to redirect to 404. Those are not the issue.

I want to redirect those wrongly formatted, but still existing URLs redirect to the sites formatted like the last row in the htaccess.

The problem is, I don't know the texts and formatting (the number of slashes) in the URL, because they were generated on the fly. **The only certain thing is the last part of the URL behind the last slash.**

Can somebody tell me, how to cut all the things before the last slash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by using:

```
RewriteRule ^.*/([^/]+-[0-9]+)$ /$1 [R=301]
```

This will redirect every request where the url ends with anything-NUMBER, e.g. `www.example.com/xxx/yyy/foobar-123` --> `www.example.com/foobar-123`

`[R=301]` will force a redirect with HTTP 301 "Moved permanently". That will tell all search engines that they should delete the old URLs and instead use the new ones.

Comment: Incidentally, `^.*/([^/]+)$` is the same as `/([^/]+)$` - the `^.*` part is superfluous.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't work :-( Now my main page is messed up too.

Comment: The above rule will rewrite all(!) urls which look like /some/thing/. If your main page uses urls which look like that than they will be rewritten, too. That is what you asked for.

Comment: Of course I don't want to change "images/mylogo.png" changed. I want to change links, which look like "something/something/anotherthing-123456" look like /anotherthing-123456". Everything else should stay the same. Your rule messes up every internal pathing. Who would want to do that? In my OP there is the last line of the htaccess, which I specially mentioned and there is the comment #This is the final output. Of course I want to keep that final output.

Comment: Please describe exactly which urls (how do thesy look like?) should not be rewritten. Give one or more examples of those urls.

Comment: There are many different URLS on my site. Internal and external. The external URLs will be created and added to a database regularly in an automated way and then presented on the website in a simplified form (rewritten by htaccess). Now I made the mistake that I didn't escape "/" from titles earlier and they got crawled by Google. I changed the URLs in the database and now they will be used right, but the already crawled URLs remain the same on Google of course.

Continued...

Comment: The URLs containing more than one slashes mess up images and divs and such, because my sites are created on the fly based on the URL clicked in Google or on the main site.

It's very complicated, but I have shown in the original post, how those URLs which I want to change look like. They contain texts and slashes in an ammount I can't know. Some of them contain hundreds of characters and dozens of slashes.

All other urls are formatted like that, what I want to get for the wrong urls.

example.com/something-123456

Comment: At the moment we simply have no clue which urls should be rewritten and which should not be rewritten. So we can only handle them all the same. As long as you can not give a brief explanation of the format of urls you want (or dont want) to be rewritten, nobody can help you. .htaccess files can not tell the difference between wrong and correct urls, we need to give some kind of formal description.

Comment: How could I tell you every single URL on a webpage? There are internal links for design like "example.com/images/mylogo.png" which of course shouldn't be rewritten. "example.com/something-123456" should not be rewritten. "example com/something/something/.../something/anotherthing-123456" should be rewritten to "example.com/anotherthing-123456" I don't know how I could describe it more comprehensible. What do you not understand from "nothing should be rewritten, except links that look like  "example.com/..../..../..../..../anotherthing-123456"?

Comment: I gave you exact examples in OP what SHOULD BE rewritten.

Comment: Adopted my answer to redirect only /.../.../somestring-somenumber

Comment: It works now! THANKS! "phew" that wasn't an easy birth, but you saved my site!

Comment: Your're welcome. Often a good description of a problem is half of the solution ;-)