# Remove part of URL after "-" by using .htaccess

Tags: php

How can I rewrite the URL using `.htaccess` using PHP

The original URL is

```
aaa.com/post/sample-word
```

I want the below URL's:

```
aaa.com/post/123456-dcddsd
aaa.com/post/213123-dfodcm
aaa.com/post/921478-gjirpg
```

to change to:

```
aaa.com/post/123456
aaa.com/post/213123
aaa.com/post/921478
```

I don't want hyphen or the word after the hyphen

Comment: Where is your ht access code?

Comment: just wordpress url

Comment: use str_replace(), or implode/explode to eliminate the string or any characters you want.

Answer (score 0):

First solution: you can manually edit the URL of any Wordpress post (just go to the Admin section and edit the URL of the post from there).

In case you insist using .htaccess then you can refer following stackoverflow [URL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/).

Another method is to use a Wordpress plugin (Ref: [URL/Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731862/how-to-remove-parts-of-url-by-rewrite-in-htaccess?rq=1)).